# The requested service could not be activated

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

Hello I have a service hosted on an IIS local server and consumed by an asp.net application

I'm pretty new at WCF so I have no idea how to know what's causing this exception

> The requested service, 'http://localhost/Service.svc/HomePageGenerator' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

it's at

```
public HomePageGenerator.HomePage homePageGenerator() {
    return base.Channel.homePageGenerator();
}
```

and here's the stack trace

```
[ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://localhost/Service.svc/HomePageGenerator' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10733331
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +336
   HomePageGenerator.IHomePageGenerator.homePageGenerator() +0
   HomePageGenerator.HomePageGeneratorClient.homePageGenerator() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e32eb7ea\44e0d8ae\App_WebReferences.dj5hozd3.0.cs:451
   _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Websites\OffTagWebsite\Default.aspx.cs:18
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9750842
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +196
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Suggest you check the event log for more information

Comment: I don't know how to check the event log

Comment: They're usually under Administrative Tools -> Event Logs